# Best design pattern for a conditional booking system

Tags: c#, oop, design-patterns

I'm building a flight booking system from a specification for my OOP class in college. The system has to be written in C#. I'm wondering what the best way to tackle the following problem would be

> The company currently operates a discount scheme. Western Isles residents get a 10% discount.
>   Scotia also records the island of residence of these passengers for marketing purposes. Business
>   travellers get a 25% discount and must supply their company name. Ordinary passengers do not
>   normally receive a discount unless it is part of a current promotion, in which case they receive a
>   5% discount.

Should I have a passenger class, from which each separate type of customer inherits from? Any help on this would be appreciated

Comment: I'd probably also use a decorator if passengers can receive multiple discounts, is that the case?

Comment: Hi Benjamin. Each customer can only receive one of the available discounts. Thanks.

Comment: Does your description mean that a passenger can get multiple discounts? Like 10% because of residence *and* 25% for business? If so, I guess one derived class per discount would not work. In a real world scenario, I would consider some simple if-statements because introducing a full fledged pattern seems way overengineered. However, if it's homework and you want to show off, maybe you can find one that better fits the "many discounts" requirement.

Comment: Youve stated passengers only get one discount? Are you *sure* thats in the spec?

Comment: Hi Jamie, yeah its not actually in the spec but I have confirmed this with my lecturer. Thanks.

Comment: @DarrenFindlay If this is for college, I'm sure your professor wants you to use the strategy pattern. It is one of the typical examples I saw in college too.

Comment: @DarrenFindlay Did you tried something or thought something?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

In my opinion you *do not* want to inherit from Passenger. Inheritance implies that the object changes in some way, but a passenger is a passenger no matter what discount he obtains. Put another way, his functionality does not change just because he gets a bigger discount.

This example you are using is very close to the examples usually given for the `Decorator` pattern, although that is usually because it demonstrates that multiple discounts can be applied to the object being decorated (Passenger in your case). Take a look at the Coffee example on wiki [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Decorator_pattern)

Another possibility is `Strategy` pattern, this gives you a clean interface for creating a Ticket for a passenger, while internally it switches the `DiscountStrategy` depending upon what type of passenger is requesting a ticket.

Comment: +1 Concerns of passenger class are orthogonal to discount logic

Comment: Thanks Jamie, great answer. I think I'm going to go with the strategy pattern as it seems most fitting. What about the face that Business customers need their business name recorded? And western Isles customer need their Island of residence recorded? This is were i get confused. Thanks again.

Comment: @DarrenFindlay - Aha, now *that* might give you a case for inheritance. The Passenger clearly has additional functionality (in this case, new fields for the extra info). As a side effect of that, you can use the type of passenger to determine the right discount strategy to use.

Comment: Excellant, thanks Jamie. Should passenger creational logic then be encapsulated? For example a passenger factory? Or factory method?

Answer (score 0):

You want to make discount policy flexible, the passengers are not really that different.

You could have a `Customer` base class from which `Passenger` and `Company` derive, but that doesn't really affect how you apply the discount logic.

Inheritance implies different behavior, but behavior of passengers doesn't change, only the applied discounts, and discount should not be a part of passenger state so it doesn't fit into that class. Additionally, many discounts are active only for some timespan, and it doesn't make sense to encode that into Customer class, you should be able to add and remove them dynamically.

As discount logic is actually a business rule which is applied at customer, it should be encapsulated into a separate set of classes. Common pattern used to implement this is [strategy](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Strategy_pattern). Depending on your design, as you want to apply different policies to different type of users, you might find [visitor](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Visitor_pattern) pattern useful or not.

Answer (score 0):

I would use a Strategy pattern as described in previous posts"Another possibility is Strategy pattern, this gives you a clean interface for creating a Ticket for a passenger, while internally it switches the DiscountStrategy depending upon what type of passenger is requesting a ticket."

Answer (score -1):

if it is all about discount shemes, it may be sufficient to just use the decorator pattern as described by others.

Then you would check the type of the interface and not of the passenger, if you want to e.g. list the number of business travellers, or residence for marketing purposes etc.